# why do I get an error message 'No module named...'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Starting from a new directory, I clone the following repository:

https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-python

I rename the cloned directory to `deribit_api_python`

In the base directory, I then have a one line Python file:

`from deribit_api_python import RestClient`

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from deribit_api_python import RestClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'RestClient'
```

Why does my code generate an error?

Answer (score 2):

in `__init__.py` file  write

```
from .deribit_api import RestClient
```

or you need to change intial calling by

```
from deribit_api_python.derbit_api import RestClient
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement the package would be to install via pip as mentioned in the repository. `pip install deribit-api` and then import it via `from deribit_api import RestClient`

Comment: you don't need to create module of package if it is being used in a project and is not distributed one